# Service выполняется не в UI Thread?

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-service, listener

Есть `Service` и `Activity`, между ними установлена связь посредством IBinder. `Activity` реализует некий интерфейс, допустим `onLoadCompleteListener`. Service вызывает метод `onLoadCompleteListener.onLoadComplete`, когда некая операция закончена.

**Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("text");
    // будет вызван Ecxeption "Only original thread that created a view..."
}
```

**Service:**

```
public onLoadCompleteListener listener;

public void onStartCommand(...)
{
    listener.onLoadComplete();
}

class SBinder extends Binder {
    Service getService(MyInterface ilistener)
    {
        listener = ilistener;
        return Service.this;
    }
}
```

*Примеры не несут никакой практической выгоды, а нужны только для объяснения вопроса*

При вызове `onLoadComplete()` приложение крашится с ошибкой "Only original thread that created a view can touch its views". Возникает вопрос: неужели сервис выполняется не в том же потоке, что и Activity как это указано в мануалах?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь для соединения с сервисом должен использоваться ServiceConnection, который асинхронно, не в UI потоке  соединяется с сервисом и по сему, видать, дальнейшее взаимодействие ведётся не в основном потоке

Comment: Ваша ошибка означает лишь то, что вы `listener.onLoadComplete();` вызываете в другом каком-то потоке. Вопрос к сервису никакого отношения не имеет, того же эффекта вы можете добиться и в activity (в asynctask'е, например, обратившись к ui в doInBackground). Если вы в каком-то методе стартуете другой поток и из него вызываете колбэк, то он будет выполняться в том же другом потоке, никакой магии автоматического возврата в главный поток не произойдет.

Answer (score 1):

`Service` в андроиде работает в главном потоке. Для выполнения в background потоке вам нужно использовать либо `AsyncTask`, либо `Thread`. Или же воспользуйтесь `IntentService`. Это подкласс обычного `Service`. У него метод `onHandleIntent` отрабатывает в background потоке.